# Whenever I wrote "style" I got an errorthe named parameter undefined

Tags: variables, intellij-idea, undefined, lib

Child: text('hi'),
style: new Textstyle()…
...
This where I faced the error"the named parameter undefined" 
And I tried to reinstall the flutter and the intellij itself
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPLmG.png)

Comment: Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And when I added after the text in child the following>>> style:new Textstyle ( color: colors.red), >>>>.    I got an error (the named parameter undefined)

Comment: i edited the question and added an image , please view it @CrazyCoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you have:

```
...
home: new Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text('works!'),
          style: new TextStyle()
        )
...
```

But [Center](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html) class doesn't have a `style` property:

```
/// A widget that centers its child within itself.
///
/// This widget will be as big as possible if its dimensions are constrained and
/// [widthFactor] and [heightFactor] are null. If a dimension is unconstrained
/// and the corresponding size factor is null then the widget will match its
/// child's size in that dimension. If a size factor is non-null then the
/// corresponding dimension of this widget will be the product of the child's
/// dimension and the size factor. For example if widthFactor is 2.0 then
/// the width of this widget will always be twice its child's width.
///
/// See also:
///
///  * [Align], which lets you arbitrarily position a child within itself,
///    rather than just centering it.
///  * [Row], a widget that displays its children in a horizontal array.
///  * [Column], a widget that displays its children in a vertical array.
///  * [Container], a convenience widget that combines common painting,
///    positioning, and sizing widgets.
///  * The [catalog of layout widgets](https://flutter.io/widgets/layout/).
class Center extends Align {
  /// Creates a widget that centers its child.
  const Center({ Key key, double widthFactor, double heightFactor, Widget child })
    : super(key: key, widthFactor: widthFactor, heightFactor: heightFactor, child: child);
}
```

So the error shown by DartAnalyser is correct and expected